# Python tkinter listbox how can i get the number of selected index

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Simply, I have a Listbox and a button (Tkinter). When I click the button I want to get the selected item's row number. Example;

Let's say I have 3 indexes in the Listbox. They are item1, item2, item3. When I select item2 and click the button I want to get 2 (The item's row), for item1 = 1, item3 = 3. Is it possible?

(p.s. Item's names will be different so I can't get the number from their name :D)

Comment: I'm a beginner so if you can explain well, it will be awesome :)

Comment: `listbox.curselection()` will return the indexes of selected items, but the index starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: PS: Next time it's better to provide a code sample formatted as a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so that someone can provide an answer that you can tick ;).